# Windows Event Viewer for Bluetooth Disconnect?

Tags: windows-10, bluetooth

I have a bluetooth mouse that is constantly disconnecting from my Windows 10 laptop (once or twice at my office, every 2-10 minutes at home).  Is there an event in the eventviewer that would indicate when this happens?  I've spent a few hours trying to find the event in the windows event viewer.

If there isn't a windows event, is there a utility that would indicate this? I'd like to create a script that will force a reconnect.

(I've tried re-pairing the devices, updating bluetooth drivers, disabling power save.)

Comment: I assume you have changed the batteries?

Comment: It's only a few weeks old, but I've swapped it with other batteries and got the same performance.